# ubuntu networking wired connection

Tags: 16.04

I tried to connect internet in ubuntu server with a wired connection. Instead of eth0 'ifconfig' cmd shows enp3s0. How I can connect my system with  the internet. Thank you for any replies...
/etc/network/interface

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried it with `auto enp3s0 && iface enp3s0 inet dhcp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the name your network adapter has, so in your case `enp3s0` instead of `eth0` :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```